# Writing the scraped results in CSV file

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to write the scraped results in a CSV file, using Python script not by passing command on terminal.

Here is the code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from my_scrapy.items import newsItem

class BbcSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "bbcnews"
    allowed_domains = ["bbc.co.uk"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology/",]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/technology-\d+']), 'parse_story')]

    def parse_story(self, response):

        story = newsItem()

        story['url'] = response.url

        story['headline'] = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()
        story['intro'] = response.css('p.introduction::text').extract()
        story['p_date'] = response.xpath("//ul/li/div[@class='date date--v2']/text()").extract()
        story['story_body'] = response.css('p.story-body__introduction::text').extract()
        return story
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does 'not by passing command on terminal' mean you don't want to use the '-t csv -o csv_output_file.csv' command line options?

Comment: yes, i don't want to pass it as -o out.csv on terminal. I just want to run my spider as scrapy crawl spider_name, and it collects results in a csv file automatically.

Comment: Please take a look at the [scrapy pipeline documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file). Maybe you can build your own csvPipeline (with some inspirations from the source code of the CsvFeedExporter).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the csv module?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

If not have a go and write where you are struggling.

Comment: You post just a copy/paste from documentation, with bad formatting

Comment: I would have added this as a comment, but since I have just joined and need 50 reputations to comment I couldn't, so I tried to help some other way. I just wanted to help him out or point him in right direction - but please delete some fake internet-point from my account or delete the answer.